# Vbscript: How to list all Internet Explorer windows in admin mode

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript, admin

I need some help on vbscript using Internet Explorer 11 under windows 7. I have discovered that when creating two (or more) IE object, when going in admin mode, only the first one is seen with  `CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows`.

To give an example of the problem, in the following code I run a sub called IE() that only creates 2 IE object by the usual way and navigate to bing and google. Then list those windows by using a loop on `CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows`.

The first run is made normally and both windows are detected, but when I relaunch the script under admin mode, when recalling the same Sub, only the first IE Object is detected:

```
path    = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").CurrentDirectory 

  If WScript.Arguments.length = 0 Then    

     ' First try, running Sub IEOpen not as admin
      IEOpen

     'relaunch script as admin
      Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
      ShellApp.ShellExecute "wscript.exe", Chr(34) & _
            WScript.ScriptFullName & " " & Chr(34) & _
            " " & Chr(34) & path &  Chr(34),"", "runas", 1
  Else
      Start
  End If

Sub Start
   'Run same Sub again but in admin mode
     IEOpen
end sub

Sub IEOpen()
  Set IE1 = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  Set IE2 = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
      IE1.Navigate "www.bing.com"
      IE2.Navigate "www.google.com"
      IE1.Visible = true
      IE2.Visible = true
      msgbox CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows.count
      For Each win In CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows
           msgbox win.LocationURL
      Next
      IE1.Quit
      IE2.Quit
End Sub
```

In my complete code I need to have two different IE and run as admin, so I'm stuck as I can't access to the properties of the second IE Object. Do you know what I'm doing wrong or if this problem can be bypassed?